# Pass validation context to associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

I'm using contexts to invoke specific validations at different points in the model lifecycle:

```
model Address
    validates :city, presence: true
    validates :street, presence: true, on: :send_letter
end

incomplete_address = Address.new(city: 'Berlin')
incomplete_address.valid? # => true
incomplete_address.valid?(:send_letter) # => false
```

This works fine for the simple case above. But, as far as I can tell, the context is ignored for any associated objects:

```
model Address
    belongs_to :country
    validates :street, presence: true, on: :send_letter
    validates_associated :country
end

model Country
    has_many :addresses
    validates :iso_alpha_3, presence: true, size: 3, on: :send_letter
end

incomplete_address = Address.new(street: 'Oranienstr', country: Country.new(name: 'Germany', iso_alpha_3: 'Invalid iso code')

incomplete_address.valid? # => true
incomplete_address.valid?(:send_letter) # => true
incomplete_address.country.valid?(:send_letter) => false
```

Question: Is this expected behaviour, or is it a bug I'm hitting? Or am I making a conceptual mistake? What's the most elegant way to validate associated models under such circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the expected behaviour, validators are executed only in the current model.
You can achieve the desired result using a custom method validator.

You can find more informations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods)

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is 3 years old but there is a slightly easier path now and an an even easier option on the horizon.

There is currently [an outstanding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/24135) that adds this functionality via a configuration option on the `validates_associated` call. In the meantime, you can add that version of `AssociatedValidator` as a separate validator (e.g. `AssociatedPreservingContextValidator`) and call `validate_with AssociatedPreservingContextValidator, :country` in `Address.